# How to add title of the image in manage display section or display it in node view page

Tags: 8, nodes, media

I want to display title property of an image in node view page.
How can I display title of an image along with image in node page?

Comment: Normally the title is an attribute of the img tag. You can change this in a field formatter and then downstream in a preprocess hook or template.

Answer (score 0):

### Custom Formatters

Try the [Custom Formatters](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) module to create a custom formatter, Tokens may help. There are some examples for inspiration: [Custom Formatter Examples](https://www.drupal.org/node/2532498).

Or implement through your own custom solution in a module or a theme: [Create a custom field formatter](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-field-formatter).

### Views Block

Another way of doing it is hiding the Image field on Manage Display, and creating a Views Block instead with a contextual node ID filter that outputs that image field along with the title. If you don't see the title available as a field in content views out of the box you can add a Relationship to that field to get it.